# Expected frequency of most frequent die roll

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, integer-partitions

Suppose we have an fair $m$-sided die, and we roll it $n$ times. What is the expected frequency $E(n, m)$ of the most frequently rolled face?

If we fix $n$ we can calculate $E(n,m)$ like so. Let $\Pi(n)$ be the set of partitions of $n$, where each partition is a weakly descending sequence of nonnegative integers, like $(5,2,2,1,1,0...)$. For each partition $\pi$, we calculate the probability that the frequency distribution equals $\pi$, then we multiply that by $\pi_1$ to get the contribution to $E$. Summing over $\Pi(n)$ gives us $E$.

I have computed the following (using Mathematica):

$\begin{align*}
E(1,m) &= 1\\
E(2,m) &= (m+1)/m\\
E(3,m) &= (m^2+3m-1)/m^2\\
E(4,m) &= (m^3+6m^2-7m+4)/m^3\\
E(5,m) &= (m^4+10m^3-25m^2+40m-21)/m^4\\
E(6,m) &= (m^5+15m^4-65m^3+195m^2-266m+126)/m^5\\
E(7,m) &= (m^6+21m^5-140m^4+665m^3-1631m^2+1911m-820)/m^6\\
E(8,m) &= (m^7+28m^6-266m^5+1820m^4-6881m^3+14140m^2-14554m+5720)/m^7
\end{align*}$

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is whether there is a closed form for E(n,m).

Comment: Hm.. I notice that the first three values of each term in the sum are (signed versions of) the Stirling numbers of the second kind: ${n \brace n}, {n \brace n-1}, {n \brace n-2}$. Struggling to find a general pattern. Seems like there should be an inclusion-exclusion argument to explain the sums.

Comment: How are you computing the probability of a given partition?

Comment: Say the partition is {7,4,4,4,1,1}, so n=21. For the 7-frequency event we have mC1 choices, for the three 4-frequency events we have (m-1)C3 choices, for the two 1-frequency events we have (m-4)C2 choices. Then we arrange the events with 21!/(7!4!4!4!1!1!).

Comment: OK that is how I was thinking... Finally back at my own computer and reproduced your table in Mathematica.

Fascinating problem. I am stumped right now but I'll keep thinking about it.

Comment: Related: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2347220?uid=3737512&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104107676271

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the maximal face has the frequency $k$, which appears $t$ times, is
$$
\begin{align*}
p_{k,t} &= m^{-n} \binom{m}{t} \left[(1+\cdots+x^{k-1})^{m-t}\right]|_{x^{n-kt}} \\ &=
m^{-n} \binom{m}{t} \left[ \frac{(1-x^k)^{m-t}}{(1-x)^{m-t}} \right]|_{x^{n-kt}} \\ &=
m^{-n} \binom{m}{t} \sum_{s=0}^{m-t} (-1)^s \binom{m-t}{s} \binom{n-kt-(s-1)(m-t)-1}{m-t-1}.
\end{align*}
$$
Here the binomial coefficients should be understood as null if "out of range". Given $p_{k,t}$, the expectation you are after is $\sum_{k,t>0} kp_{k,t}$. I'm not sure there is any more succinct way to write this expression. Compared to your formula, though, this expression should be more efficient to compute. However, this expression doesn't make it immediately clear why the result should be polynomial in $m$, given $n$.

Comment: I do not think this is the question being asked... The question is: what is the expected frequency of the most frequent face, not what is the expected face value of the most frequent face.

Comment: @A.E The expected face value of the most frequent face, for $n$ large, should be very close to $(m+1)/2$, even exactly this value if we choose a random face among those with the maximum frequency. However, this is not what this answer is trying to find. Perhaps you should try to read it again.

Comment: @A.E I corrected the typo that confused you: $k$ is the frequency rather the face value. The formulas, however, remain the same.

Comment: I am still confused as to why $k$ and $t$ are both necessary. You say $k$ is the frequency of the most frequent face, and that $t$ is the number of times it appears... Are these not the same?

Comment: @A.E It could happen that the maximal frequency appears on several faces.

Comment: Oh I see, I was totally misinterpreting that. My mistake